# Does the mentioned sentence properly mean what I intend?

Tags: meaning-in-context, sentence-meaning, sentence-structure

There are things (A, B, and C), and I am entitled to be informed about all of them equally. That means I am entitled to be informed about A as much as I am to be informed about B and C, and so on.

Now, is the following sentence correct?

> The things of which I am equally entitled to be informed.

My question is about whether "equally" in this sentence properly indicates that I am entitled to be informed about all the things equally.

If not, I would appreciate your suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence is grammatically correct, but **the concept of being informed on different topics in equal measure** is unclear without additional explanation.

The sentence appears to mean that **you** are equal (*to someone else*) and so you are entitled to all the information they have been given.

> I am *equally entitled* to be informed about these things.

Re-arranging the sentence into other grammatically correct forms can help:

> The things, of which I am entitled to be informed in equal measure, …
>
> I am entitled to be informed about each thing in equal measure.

But the concept is still unclear without a further explanation.

Comment: The *exact* meaning of "in equal measure" here remains somewhat unclear to me, even after discarding the possible interpretation *having a right to be informed which is equal to some other contextually relevant person[s] right to be informed.* I'm not sure I can come up with a real-world context to differentiate between two other possibilities, but there's (1) ***having the same right** to be informed,* and (2) *having the right to be **informed to the same level** [of detail].*

Comment: I Agree. Adding "measure" does not really make it clearer, it only helps to distance it from the most obvious misinterpretation. The concept has to be explained.

Comment: After giving it some thought, I can imagine a context where my two alternative readings *might* have real-world implications. Suppose that ***one*** of "these things" happens to be a subject on which I'm already an expert (in a general sense). In that case, my rights under sense #1 could be satisfied by *being given less information* for that subject (simply because I don't need so much background material). Where sense #2 might imply that I'm entitled to get the same level of detail for each subject, even though I don't actually *need* that much for my "specialist subject".